# How show and filter search text interactively in separate buffer?

Tags: completion, isearch, history

Emacs 26.1

Suppose I find any text in buffer:

1. `C-s`
2. find_text_1
3. Input `Enter`
4. `C-s`
5. find_text_2
6. Input `Enter`

So if I want to again find text `find_text_1` I press `C-s` then `M-p`. 
OK. It's work. Nice.
If I want to sea all search texts I press `C-M-i`. But when I select some text it print this text in buffer. But I need to search text (not print).
[image]

[image]

But suppose I has 20 search texts in minibuffer history.
So if I need to find e.g. second text (2/20) I need to press `M-p` 18 times. 
It's not very good. And it's very slow.

The question is:
Is it possible to show buffer that contain all `Isearch` find text?
And I want to filter them on fly (interactively).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

`C-M-i` in Isearch is pretty lame, as you indicate. In general, in vanilla Emacs completion is not incremental, in the sense that it does not continue completing (updating the possible completions) as you type (change your minibuffer input).

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you don't have this problem - completion is incremental, by default.

In particular, for Isearch `C-M-i` shows you the possible completions in buffer `*Completions*`, and those candidates get updated automatically, incrementally as you type.  You can also cycle through candidates with `TAB` - you can combine (1) typing text to refine the set of candidates and (2) cycling, to quickly get the candidate you want.

See [Icicles - Isearch Enhancements](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Isearch_Enhancements#SearchStringCompletion) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in isearch you can do <kbd>C-M-i</kbd> to pop up a buffer containing the previous search strings.

<kbd>C-h f</kbd>`isearch-forward` will give you the (long) description of everything that's possible in isearch.

Comment: But it not interactively. It's not very comfortable to select desire text. And when I select some text it PRINT text in buffer. But I need to search (not print)

Comment: I update my post.

Comment: The way `C-M-i` works is that after you use it the first time, you type some text, then `C-M-i` again. I agree the interface is somewhat confusing, it looks like you can just select the completion.